# node.js: access handlebars helper like javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

In my node.js project I want to pass some information as javascript object to a handlebars helper.

In my node app I have this:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
hbs.registerHelper("infos", function() {
  return {
    project: {
      title: "In Development"
    }
  }
});
```

and then in my handlebars template I have this

```
<h1>{{infos.project.title}}</h1>
```

But all I get for output is `<h1></h1>`.

Do I have to do it in a different way?

Comment: In your template you are not calling `infos` as a helper, but as an object within your template data.

Comment: thanks. i know now what you mean. so what I want to do is not possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You say you want to "pass information ... to a handlebars helper", but your code example suggests you want to _return_ javascript data from a helper. Returning a JS object from a helper doesn't make sense because the purpose of a helper is to return a string of HTML.

Comment: Ok. So how would you do it if you wanted to return plain javascript objects / json?

Comment: You _wouldn't_ do that. The purpose of Handlebars is to give it data and have it return a string of HTML markup with the data substituted. If there is data you want your template to have, you should pass it to the template method, not return it from a helper.

Comment: I see. You really helped me then